# Hyperledger Fabric and Node.js creation of environment successfully and getting some error in execution

Tags: node.js, hyperledger

I am creating network but after that when I'm running the `query.js` and I am getting this errors:

> Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1200
>
> Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().

==== C stack trace ===============================

> node(v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x16) [0x1598936]
>       node(V8_Fatal+0xd6) [0x15935c6]
>       node(v8::Template::Set(v8::Local, v8::Local, v8::PropertyAttribute)+0xf7) [0xa9a447]
>       /home/ubramanyam/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary

Answer (score 0):

@Subramanyam , What OS and Node version are you using ?

Can you also confirm if you followed instructions given here

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#node-js-runtime-and-npm